# My problem with the size of the number in the My_Mastermind minigame

Tags: c

can you help me with the size of the digits, for example, when I enter 01234, then everything works as it should, but it shouldn’t, the limit of digits should be within four.When I enter some four-digit number, everything works as it should work. But when some five-digit, six-digit or even more, then everything works as if it should be, but it should not work like that. And when I enter numbers that are less than four-digit, for example 123 , then it gives an error and it's good. But when I enter numbers that are more than four digits, it does not give an error and works as if it should be so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct s_mastermind {
    int my_attempt;
    char* my_code;
} my_mastermind;

my_mastermind* settings_function(my_mastermind* mastermind, int argc, char** argv);
int checking_for_correctness_num(char* _string);
int wrong_input(int progress,char* num_code);
my_mastermind* my_function();
int check_function(char* string);
char* input_function();
int mis_placed_pieces(char* bit, char* num_code);
int well_placed_pieces(char* bit, char* num_code);
int code_checker(char* bit, char* num_code);
char* size_of_function(char* strye);

char* my_strcpy(char* num1, char* num2) {
   for(int i = 0; num2[i] != 0; i++) {
       num1[i] = num2[i];
   }
   return num1;
}

int my_strlen(char* num1) {
    return (*num1) ? my_strlen(++num1) + 1 : 0;
}



my_mastermind* my_function() {
    my_mastermind* num = malloc(sizeof(my_mastermind));
    num->my_code = malloc(5);
    num->my_code[4] = '\0';
    my_strcpy(num->my_code, "");
    num->my_attempt = 10;
    return num;
}




my_mastermind* settings_function(my_mastermind* mastermind, int argc, char** argv) {
            char* bit;
            for(int i = 0; i < argc;) {
        if (my_strlen(argv[i]) == 2 && argv[i][0] == '-') {
            if(argv[i][1] == 'c') {
                char* num_code = argv[i + 1];
                if(wrong_input(argc,num_code) != 0) {
                    break;
                }
                my_strcpy(mastermind->my_code, num_code);
            }else if(argv[i][1] == 't') {
                if(checking_for_correctness_num(argv[i + 1]) == 0) {
                    mastermind->my_attempt = check_function(argv[i + 1]);
                }
            } else {
                printf("WRONG FLAG RESTART THE GAME!!!\n");
            }
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    return mastermind;
}





int wrong_input(int progress,char* num_code) {
    // if(my_strlen(num_code) != 4) {
    //     printf("Code bigger than 4\n");
    // }
    if(checking_for_correctness_num(num_code) == 1) {
        printf("Wrong input!\n> ");
        fflush(stdout);
        char* code = input_function();
        char* variable = size_of_function(code);
        free(code);
        int results = 1;
        if(wrong_input(progress,variable) == 0) {
            results = code_checker(num_code, variable);
        }
        free(variable);
        return results;
        } 
        return 0;
}


int checking_for_correctness_num(char* _string) {
    for(int i = 0; _string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if(!(_string[i] >= '0' && _string[i] <= '9')) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}



int check_function(char* string) {
    int check_num = 0;
    for(int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        check_num = check_num * 10 + (string[i] - '0');
    }
    return check_num;
}

char* input_function() {
    char* getting = malloc(101);
    getting[100] = '\0';
    read(0, getting, 100);
    fflush(stdout);
    return getting;
}

int game_progress(int progress, char* bit) {
    printf("Round: %d\n> ", progress);
    fflush(stdout);
    char* code = input_function();
    char* variable = size_of_function(code);
    free(code);
    int results = 1;
    if(wrong_input(progress,variable) == 0) {
         results = code_checker(bit, variable);
    }
    free(variable);
    return results;
}


void game_action(my_mastermind* mastermind) {
    int current_try = 0;
     for (;current_try < mastermind->my_attempt;) {
       int results = game_progress(current_try, mastermind->my_code);
        current_try += 1;
        

        if(results == 0) {
            printf("Congratz! You did it!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    
}


int code_checker(char* bit, char* num_code) {
    int good_w = well_placed_pieces(bit, num_code);
    int not_good_m = mis_placed_pieces(bit, num_code);
    if(good_w == 3 || good_w == 2 || good_w == 1 || not_good_m == 3 || not_good_m == 2 || not_good_m == 1){
    printf("Well placed pieces: %d\nMisplaced pieces: %d\n---\n", good_w,not_good_m);    
    }


    if(good_w == 4) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}


int well_placed_pieces(char* bit, char* num_code) {
    int number = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (bit[i] == num_code[i]) {
            number += 1;
        } 
    }
    return number;
    
}

int mis_placed_pieces(char* bit, char* num_code) {
     int number = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < 4) {
        i++;
        if (bit[i] == num_code[i]) {
            number += 1;
        }
    }
    return number;
    
}

char* size_of_function(char* strye) {
    char* new_string = malloc(5);
    new_string[4] = '\0';
    for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++){
        new_string[i] = strye[i];
    }
    return new_string;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("Will you find the secret code?\n---\n");
    my_mastermind* mastermind = my_function();
    settings_function(mastermind, argc, argv);
    game_action(mastermind);
    free(mastermind);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: And why are you reimplementing the standard string copy and length functions? Especially, why do you implement `my_strlen` in a recursive manner?

Comment: Because I'm not allowed to use the string.h library in this project

Comment: The function `size_of_function()` makes the assumption that 4 characters were entered regardless of the actual. Any more than 4 will be ignored, and with only three the 4th is undefined. Suggest: don't use `read()` with `stdin` use a text based function.

Comment: I don't understand how to do this, can you explain or show?

Comment: As it stands, `read()` returns the number of bytes read which you ignore. Use that value.

Comment: But how to use it and where? Sorry, the questions may seem stupid, I'm just a beginner in C

Comment: `if(read(0, getting, 100) != 5) { /* handle error */ }`. Four digits plus newline is five.

Comment: THANK YOU VERU MUCH WEATHER VANE YOU ARE MY SAVIOR

Comment: Welcome, but please do not SHOUT!

Comment: It is completely unclear to write “everything works as it should, but it shouldn’t.” When describing a problem, state exactly what input is given (not “some four-digit number” but “0123 followed by pressing enter”), exactly what behavior is observed (what the program prints or other messages that appear), and what behavior is desired instead.

Comment: @Alucard11123 `my_strcpy()` fails to copy the _null character_.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you `size_of_function` assumes the input string is exactly 4 character long, not counting the `'\0'`. You should either check if the input string and return a error via a NULL pointer, or fully copy the string and check later.

Returning a NULL pointer require the least modification. You can do it by checking the input string size first :

```c
char* size_of_function(char* strye) {

    if(my_strlen(strye) != 4)
        return NULL;

    char* new_string = malloc(5);
    new_string[4] = '\0';
    for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++){
        new_string[i] = strye[i];
    }    
    if (strye[4] == '\r' || strye[4] == '\n' || strye[4] == '\0')
        return new_string;

    free(new_string);
    return NULL;
}
```

Then, in `wrong_input()`, check if `num_code` is NULL :

```c
int wrong_input(int progress,char* num_code) {
    if(num_code == NULL || checking_for_correctness_num(num_code) == 1) {
        printf("Wrong input!\n> ");
        fflush(stdout);
        char* code = input_function();
        char* variable = size_of_function(code);
        free(code);
        int results = 1;
        if(wrong_input(progress,variable) == 0) {
            results = code_checker(num_code, variable);
        }
        free(variable);
        return results;
        } 
        return 0;
}
```

It is *critical* to check if `num_code` is NULL before calling `checking_for_correctness_num()`. In C the `||` operator evaluates the left operand first and skip the second operand evaluation if the first one is true. This way we can ensure that we never pass a NULL pointer to `checking_for_correctness_num()`.

---

`wrong_input()` is called recursively and allocates memory without freeing it before calling itself. This can eat up memory fast and is generality considered to be bad practice.

Also, you've implemented `my_strlen()` as a recursive function, which isn't necessary. Using a loop is better :

```c
int my_strlen(char* num1) {
    int index = 0;
    while(num1[index++]); //Note that 'index' is post-incremented
    return index - 1; //Subtract one to account for the last post increment 
}
```

Comment: Yes that's true, I'll edit my answer. I've put the comment to highlight why should return `index - 1` but I forgot to actually subtract 1

Comment: Consider `size_t index = 0; while(num1[index]) index++; return index;`.

Comment: Elzadair, thanks but your variant don't work. Because when i input any number it's says wrong input

Comment: There was a typo where in `size_of_function()`, it's not `if (my_strlen(* strye) != 4)`, but `if (my_strlen(strye) != 4)`. I edited my aswer

Comment: @Alucard11123, I realised that checking for the length of the string is not enough, as it contains an end of line character. I added a check to make sure that the string terminates with an end of line or a null character. If the string is one character too short, it will be 4 character long including the end of line, but this will be caught later by `checking_for_correctness_num()`